# Help discuss why a probability is incorrect.

Tags: probability

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ consisting of $2n$ vertices, $i.e. |V|=2n$, and let $H$ be a subset of $V$ consisting of $n$ vertices, and let $\bar H = V \backslash H$. Now randomly place an edge on the graph, and what is the probability that the edge happens to connect $H$ and $\bar H$ (i.e. one endpoint of the edge is in H while the other is in $\bar H$)?

**Method 1**:
There are $C_{2n}^{2}$ (denotes $2n$ chooses $2$) possible positions for the edge, and $n^2$ of them are between $H$ and $\bar H$. Then the probability of the edge connecting $H$ and $\bar H$ is $\frac{n^2}{C_{2n}^{2}}=\frac{n^2}{n(2n-1)}$.

**Method 2**:
View the two endpoints of the edge as being randomly chosen from the $2n$ vertexes. The the probability for the edge to cross $H$ and $\bar H$ is $\frac{n}{2n}\times \frac{n}{2n-1}=\frac{n^2}{n(2n-1)}$, which is consistent with method 1.

**Method 3**:
View $H$ and $\bar H$ as two bags of vertices and the end points of the edge are randomly chosen from the two bags. Thus the probability is $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

I am not completely sure but method 3 intuitively looks incorrect. Anyone can help give a discussion that method 3 is indeed wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The third method is *almost* right. The probability the first vertex is from $H$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. **Given that**, the probability the second is from $\bar{H}$ is $\frac{n}{2n-1}$.  So we ger probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{n}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{n}{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two vertices are different: One vertex is from one of the sets; the other vertex has a probability of $\frac{n}{2n-1}$ of being from the other set.  So I would agree with your results in methods 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If interested, perhaps you can help with a related discussion here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491000/probabilistic-approach-to-prove-a-graph-theory-theorem/1493269?noredirect=1#comment3043644_1493269

Answer (score 1):

If you prohibit edges connecting vertices to themselves then 1 and 2 are correct while 3 is wrong.

The error in 3 would then be that there is a $\frac{1}{2n}$ probability that you choose the same vertex twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If interested, perhaps you can help with a related discussion here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491000/probabilistic-approach-to-prove-a-graph-theory-theorem/1493269?noredirect=1#comment3043644_1493269